# The MSDTC transaction manager's WS-AtomicTransaction protocol service 'Version10' is disabled and cannot unmarshal incoming transactions

Tags: wcf, transactions, msdtc, wsat

I have  my binding specified like this in the Service hosted in windows server 2008.

```
<bindings>
<wsHttpBinding>
<binding name="transactionalWsHttpBinding"
         transactionFlow="true" />
</wsHttpBinding>
</bindings>
```

I have not installed the WSAtomicTransaction roles in the server where the service is hosted.

when I am trying to consume the above hosted service from a different machine, I am getting the following error message.

```
The flowed transaction could not be unmarshaled. The following exception    occurred: The MSDTC transaction manager's WS-AtomicTransaction protocol service 'Version10' is disabled and cannot unmarshal incoming transactions.
```

should I install the ws-atomic feature ? If I am trying to install the WSAtomic transaction feature in Server, I am forced to add a certificate, should I implement the certificate based authentication?

Answer (score 3):

**This worked for me. You may try this.**

Open **component services** in **server** machine and expand component services and then expand **computers** expand **my computer** and expand **distributed transaction coordinator** right click **local DTC** open properties:
  Go to Security tab, enable Network DTC Access and then enable *Allow Inbound* in Transaction manager communication leave other settings.

Now open Component Services in **Client machine** follow above and go to local DTC properties open security tab , enable Network DTC Access and then enable *Allow Outbound* in Transaction manager communication leave other settings.